# How to use mDNS in AngularJS / ionic?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to use this cordova plugin to use mDNS: 
https://github.com/stevenpack/phonegap-multicastdns

But there is no example code or guides, and I am quite new to angularJS and Ionic. So how to use this plugin? and how can I derive that from the plugin code?

This is what I've got so far:

Added the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/stevenpack/phonegap-multicastdns.git
```

It went ok and I now have a "plugins/com.koalasafe.cordova.plugin.multicastdns" folder.

Now I guess I will need to include it to my controller and use the functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your angular code by the following way

```
MulticastDNSPlugin.query(host, multicastIP, port, successCallback, errorCallback)
```

For more help create issues on author source directory [here](https://github.com/stevenpack/phonegap-multicastdns/issues) and to understand the flow of customize plugin refer this [link](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-how-to-write-a-phonegap-plugin-for-android/)

Hopes this will help you !

Comment: But shouldn't I include the plugin somewhere?.. If I just use the code you suggest I get: "ReferenceError: MulticastDNSPlugin is not defined" :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, prefer `ionic` over `cordova`. Mostly ionic just defers to the underlying cordova command, but sometimes it does more, such as maintain packages.json. So:

`ionic plugin add https://github.com/stevenpack/phonegap-multicastdns.git`

Now you should have a `/plugins/com.koalasafe.cordova.plugin.multicastdns` folder.

And your package.json should have something like:

```
 "cordovaPlugins": [
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/stevenpack/phonegap-multicastdns",
      "id": "com.koalasafe.cordova.plugin.multicastdns"
    },
```

Which you can call like this:

```
$window.multicastDNS.query("some host", "224.0.0.251", 5353, function (data) {
                    $log.info("MulticastDNS query success.Callback data: " + data);
                }, function (reason) {
                    $log.error("MulticastDNS query failed: " + reason);
                });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Do I have to include anything in my controller dependencies? Right now I get: "ReferenceError: CordovaFacade is not defined".

Comment: Sorry, just updated answer. The plugin adds the property to the global window object (ouch). Look for the <clobbers> tag in plugin.xml. So, no, you don't need a controller per-se, but you should create a controller or service to expose it to your app so it's testable. In my case, it was called CordovaFacade

Comment: Cool! Getting closer! :) .. Now I get: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined" in the browser - but $window.multicastDNS should still be defined in the browser right?

Comment: Unfortunately,same error on android: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined".. :/

Comment: All plugins basically work the same. Once integrated, they 'clobber' a property on window or window.plugins. Have a look the most basic plugin you can find (toast for example "nl.x-services.plugins.toast") to check your build process is OK before trying to get multicast to work. The ionic forum should have some help too.

Comment: Cool! Got it to work by moving "www/android/MulticastDNS.js" to "www/MulticastDNS.js". Now I get no errors and $window.MulticastDNS is there! Thank you very much for the help, much appriciated!! Last thing though - I never get any answers from the module - ie. the callbacks are never called? any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @Jolle hey can you post an example or an detailed answer please?